# Converting String to SimpleDateFormat incorrect result

Tags: android

Can you guys advice why I have incorrect result on the end on this method?

```
public static String convertDateStringToHumanReadable(String dateToConvert) {
    // dateToConvert is 1981-03-17T00:00:00
    String DATE_FORMAT_PATTERN_INPUT = "yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ss";
    String DATE_FORMAT_PATTERN_OUTPUT = "dd-mm-yyyy";
    SimpleDateFormat inputDate = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_PATTERN_INPUT);
    Date dateToParse = inputDate.parse(dateToConvert, new ParsePosition(0));
    // the dateToParse.toString() is Sat Jan 17 00:00:00 EET 1981
    // Why is it Jan, I'm expecting for March

    SimpleDateFormat outputDate = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_PATTERN_OUTPUT);

    return outputDate.format(dateToParse);
}
```

Comment: Use MM for Month. ;)

Comment: As an addition to what @JoopEggen suggested, make sure to check the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for the full format specification.

Comment: @adrianp thanks for the suggestion, will definitely do, but why did you suggest so, do you see something odd in the code snippet?

Comment: @siik No, but the mentioned reference would have clarified you on the `MM` issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MM` instead of `mm`

```
 String DATE_FORMAT_PATTERN_INPUT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss";
 String DATE_FORMAT_PATTERN_OUTPUT = "dd-MM-yyyy";
```